# GWT add InlineLabels to paragraph or div with text

Tags: java, gwt, text, widget, label

I need to do something like this:

```
<p>
    This is list of inline labels: <span> label1 </span>, <span> label2 </span>, ...
</p>
```

How do I do that in GWT? (preferably using InlineLabel widgets and may be FlowPanel as a container)

I mean I can't find a way to append spans into paragraph's text. 
Can't use setInnerHTML() or something like that because I need to add some event handlers to spans.

Thanks in advance.

**UPD:**

I've found a solution myself. 
Here is a snippet of what you can do in such cases:

```
FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
flowPanel.add(new InlineLabel("inline_label"));
Node textNode = Document.get().createTextNode(", ");
flowPanel.getElement().appendChild(textNode);
flowPanel.add(new InlineLabel("inline_label2"));
```

That's it. If somebody has better solution or anything to add, you're welcome.

Thank you everybody.

PS couldn't post it as an answer cause of my low rating. It's my first question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML class for render this type of controls.Below is the example.

```
String htmlstr ="<p>This is list of inline labels: <span> label1 </span>, <span> label2 </span>, ...</p>";
    HTML html=new HTML(htmlstr);
```

Comment: Then use lebel which is provided by the GWT i.e Label class.And click of that label fire an event.

Comment: yeah that is a solution but I could not find the way to add text between those labels. And now I've found one (see UPD.)